Best way to download a file in radzen blazor
What would be the best approach to create a download button in radzen?
I found some solutions for this in the internet, they work, but none of them seems good for me.
One solution would be to create a rest endpoint which just returns the file, which you want to download. This endpoint can then be called directly within C#, which triggers a download.
Another solution would be to use javascript, creating a <a> tag, setting the href attribute to the filepath and simulating a click event on it.
As you can see those solutions are all kind of handicrafted and there seems to be no best practice for this.
Is this the case? Or am i missing something?

I don't think there is a nice way to download files. Either use plain C# or use Javascript for that.
I used JavaScript in my Blazor page, maybe my code helps. The first function downloads a file based on a stream and the second function based on a url that returns a stream.
In C#, I just call the function like that: await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("triggerFileDownload", Document.FileName, Document.DownloadUrl);
window.downloadFileFromStream = async (fileName, contentStreamReference) => {
    const arrayBuffer = await contentStreamReference.arrayBuffer();
    const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer]);
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    const anchorElement = document.createElement('a');
    anchorElement.href = url;
    anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
    anchorElement.click();
    anchorElement.remove();
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

window.triggerFileDownload = (fileName, url) => {
    // Open a new tab
    const newTab = window.open(url, '_blank');

    // Wait for the new tab to load
    newTab.onload = () => {
        const anchorElement = newTab.document.createElement('a');
        anchorElement.href = url;
        anchorElement.download = fileName ?? '';
        anchorElement.click();
        anchorElement.remove();

        // Close the new tab after the download is triggered
        newTab.close();
    };
};

